# How to login and register to header of wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, authentication, menu, header

I want to add login and register at the top right corner in the main menu of wordpress site. So is there a plugin out there which can do this and login and password textboxes should show horizontally aligned just like we have in facebook. So how we can do this .. is there any plugin for that or any coding that we can do to achieve this. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php if (!(current_user_can('level_0'))){ ?>
            <h2>Login Form</h2>
            <form action="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-login.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="log" id="log" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars(stripslashes($user_login), 1) ?>" size="20" />
            <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" size="20" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="button" />
             <p>
                   <label for="rememberme"><input name="rememberme" id="rememberme" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="forever" /> Remember me</label>
                   <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
                </p>
            </form>
            <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword">Recover password</a>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <h2>Logout</h2>
            <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>">logout</a><br />
            <a href="http://phprocks.letsnurture.com/">admin</a>
            <?php }?>
```

Comment: Add this code and add custome css

Comment: Thanks Krunal .... you did the job .... wow ! I am your fan ! :)